# Perl not including custom modules

Tags: perl, module, perl-module

I recently had to move from a shared account into a VPS, ever since I moved into the VPS I cannot get some Perl scripts that were not written by me to work anymore.

The main script starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

BEGIN{ push @INC, '../'; }

use CGI qw/:standard *div *form *script/;  
use Vamp::Config qw/:site/;
use Vamp::Users;
use Vamp::Utils;
use Vamp::HTML;
use strict;
use warnings;
```

From my limited knowledge of Perl, I can tell that it is trying to use some custom Perl modules (Config, Users, Utils & HTML). However, there is something here that is not allowing them to be used.

The folder structure looks like this:

- login/index.pl
- Vamp/Config.pm

And this is how one of those modules is written:

```
package Vamp::Config;

BEGIN{ push @INC, '../' }

use Exporter;
use strict;
use warnings;

our @ISA = ("Exporter");
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/%DB $HOME_URL $ADMIN_URL $SITE_ROOT/;
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    database => [qw/%DB/],
    site    => [qw/$HOME_URL $SITE_ROOT/],
    admin   => [qw/$ADMIN_URL/]
);

our %DB = (
    LIVE    => {
        DATASOURCE  => 'DBI:mysql:vamplets:localhost',
        USERNAME    => 'example', 
        PASSWORD    => 'example'
    },
    DEV     => {
        DATASOURCE  => 'DBI:mysql:Vamplets:localhost',
        USERNAME    => 'example',
        PASSWORD    => 'example'
    },
    DEV_ADMIN   => {
        DATASOURCE  => 'DBI:mysql:VampletsAdmin:localhost',
        USERNAME    => 'example',
        PASSWORD    => 'example'
    },
    ADMIN   => {
        DATASOURCE  => 'DBI:mysql:vampletsadmin:localhost',
        USERNAME    => 'example',
        PASSWORD    => 'example'
    }
);

our $HOME_URL = 'http://www.vamplets.com';
#our $HOME_URL = 'http://localhost/vamplets';
#our $ADMIN_URL = 'http://localhost/vamplets/admin';
our $ADMIN_URL = 'http://www.vamplets.com/admin';
our $SITE_ROOT = "/home/content/13/5396413/html/";
#our $SITE_ROOT = "C:/xampp/htdocs/vamplets/";
```

I've tried so many different things I really just don't know what to do anymore.

I just keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

I know Perl is installed and working as I've used this to check: https://ip-50-63-189-142.ip.secureserver.net/cgi-bin/perldiver/perldiver.pl

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Are you sure its /Vamps/Config.pm? If so, that might be the problem.  It should be /Vamp/Config.pm

Comment: Next time, please provide the error you are getting.

Comment: @DiabJerius Sorry it is /Vamp/Config.pm (Edited).

Comment: @ikegami I added the error I'm getting which is a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: That's from Apache, not Perl. Perl writes its errors to STDERR, which you should have your web server write to a log file.

Comment: You can add `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` to send the errors to the browser for debugging purposes. Not recommended for production.

Comment: `Can't locate Vamp/Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/sbin/.. /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd)` Error from error logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem #1

The package directive says

```
 package Vamp::Config;
```

so you are correctly using

```
 use Vamp::Config;
```

but that means the file MUST be named

```
 Vamp/Config.pm
```

You said it's named

```
 Vamps/Config.pm
```

---

### Problem #2

For starters,

```
 BEGIN { push @INC, '../'; }
```

can be written more clearly as

```
 use lib '..';
```

It's also better because it puts the directories at the front of the path, and it adds corresponding arch directories if they exist.

---

Relative paths in `@INC` are treated just like relative paths almost everywhere else: relative to the current work directory. You want to look in a path relative to the directory in which the script resides (not in a path relative to the current work directory), so you need to provide an absolute path build from that directory.

Replace

```
 BEGIN { push @INC, '../'; }    # Buggy
```

with

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/..";
```

If the library dircetory was more sensibly named `../lib` (e.g. `lib/Vamp/Config.pm`), then you could simply use

```
use mylib;
```

Comment: `lib` and `FindBin` are core modules. `mylib` isn't.

Comment: Sorry @ikegami... The folder is "Vamp", that was a typo. However, I changed the way it includes the libraries and it still not working, I instantly get a 500 Error when trying to go to the URL. [link](http://vamplets.com/login/)

Comment: I tried using `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` to no avail. I did check the error logs and i keep getting a "is not imported" & "will not stay shared" errors

Comment: Those are unrelated to the problem you described ("Perl not including custom modules"), and you didn't provide any information about those. If you can't fix those, please post a proper new question including a minimal runnable demonstration of the problem.